# Use constants in cucumber?

Tags: testing, cucumber, frank

I have about 20 Scenarios that use the same integer to specify the row number of the tableviewcell.  There was a recent change to the product and I had to change all 20 scenarios only by changing that row number.  At the moment I would prefer not to make a step specific for that row as I've got about 30 different rows to deal with:

I'd rather do:

```ruby
Given /^I am on the page labeled "([^"]+)" on row number (\d*)$/ do |page_name, row_number|
     steps %Q{
       When I scroll down #{row_number} rows in table "LeftMenu"
       And I touch the TableViewCell marked "#{page_name}"
     }
end
```

rather than:

```ruby
Then /^I select specificName$/ do
  scroll_down(24)
end
```

Can I use a constant in cucumber? Something like this:

```ruby
const ROW_NUM 24

Then I select "tableViewCellName" at row number ROW_NUM
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass the constant directly to the step definition. However, you could have the step definition check if the value passed matches a constant.

For example, with the following step:

```
ROW_NUM = 24

Then /I select "tableViewCellName" at row number (.+)/ do |row|
    row = (Kernel.const_get row rescue row.to_i)
    p row
end
```

You could call it with the ROW_NUM "constant":

```
Then I select "tableViewCellName" at row number ROW_NUM
#=> 24
```

Or with a specific row number:

```
Then I select "tableViewCellName" at row number 1
#=> 1
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several workarounds, not all of them will be appropiate for your case

1. You can group all the test cases for one row into one big test case and then call

   `When I test row 23`
2. You can have a step that will save the row number into a variable
   `When I prepare to test row 23
   And then I do something with the row I am testing
   Then something is displayed in the row I am testing`
3. Use a table
   `When I test the following rows with data:
     | 23 | something | something else |
     | 26 | something | something else | 
     | 28 | something | something else |`